# How do we prove that the area under a steeper curve is smaller?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

[image]I want to prove that

$\int_a^b \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x > \int_a^b \! g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$

if $f(x)$ is less steep than $g(x)$ and $a = g(x) \cap f(x)$ . Additionally, once we shift $g(x)$ out until $g(x) \cap f(x) = b$ we have the reverse result. 
This seems obvious once I graph it out, but I don't know how to prove it rigorously.

EDIT: by steep I mean $|\frac{df}{dx}| < |\frac{dg}{dx}|$

EDIT 2: I tried to find a similar picture. This one has the axes reversed. Source: https://web.stanford.edu/~jay/micro_class/lecture8.pdf

Comment: First define "less steep then" rigourously.

Comment: It's also not entirely clear what you mean by $a=g(x)\cap f(x).$ Supposing you mean to use the fundamental set of ordered pairs representation of a function, a single $x$ value like $a$ would not in any sense equal a function set intersection.

Comment: I just edited my question to make it clearer! Sorry

Comment: It's not clear what $a,b,f,g$ correspond to in the picture you added. But I can make a guess: By "$a=g(x)\cap f(x)$", which doesn't make sense, are you trying to say that the graphs of $f$ and $g$ meet at $x=a$? You can say that simply as $f(a)=g(a)$.

Comment: If so, the result follows as long as you add the additional condition that the slopes are negative, like in your picture: $\mathrm dg/\mathrm dx < \mathrm df/\mathrm dx < 0$. Then $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x > a$, and so the same holds for their integrals.